# Which is better approach for encrypt and decrypt data??

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, encryption

i want to encrypt the data. still i am following to do this on ASP.NET Pages. i came to know that we can apply encryption/decryption on data at Backend means on SQL SERVER. I want to know which is the better way. Will i change it to on SQL SERVER or will go with as it is?

I have studied [This link to study](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/28/sql-server-introduction-to-sql-server-encryption-and-symmetric-key-encryption-tutorial-with-script/)  which say only required columns should be encrypt/decrypt, not whole database. So please let me know which is better way from both of them.

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247797/sql-server-vs-net-encryption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I would say is that the data and the key are stored on the SQL Server.  That means if a user was able to get some type of administrative access, or with the right privileges you would potentially compromise all your encrypted data.

The other problem is what happens if the database is stolen, and then later on some vulnerability was found with the mechanism that SQL server was using?  These things happen such as when the padding oracle bug was found with scriptresource.axd http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/09/fear-uncertainty-and-and-padding-oracle.html .